# every non-finite set intersects non-void open set

Tags: general-topology

From General Topology by Kelley.

> A separable space may fail to satisfy the $2^{nd}$ axiom of countability.
>   For example, let $X$ be an uncountable set with the topology consisting of the void set and the complements of finite sets. Then every non-finite set is dense because *it intersects every non-void open set.*
>   On the other hand ...

Why in this case every non-finite set intersects every non-void open set?

*Definition*

> A topological space $X$ is **separable** iff there is a countable subset which is dense in $X$.

Comment: In that example, the non-void open sets are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the non-finite set doesn't intersect a non-void open set, it must be contained inside the complement of that open set, which is finite.

Comment: I don't follow the reasoning. Why it must be contained inside the complement of that open set? Shouldn't it be the complement itself of that open set thus, infinite?  
I'm sorry for not replying for so long. My mind was engaged in other things.

Comment: Let $Y$ be a non-finite set and $U$ be a nonempty open set. Suppose $U\cap Y=\emptyset$. Then $$Y=Y\cap (U\cup U^{\complement})=(Y\cap U) \cup (Y\cap U^{\complement})=\emptyset\cup (Y\cap U^{\complement})=Y\cap U^{\complement}\subseteq U^{\complement}.$$

Comment: Isn't complement of open set closed?

Comment: @flowian Yes, that's true by definition. Now look at the topology. It consists of the empty set and the **complements of finite sets**. Now consider the open set $U$. By definition of the topology, $U=X\setminus \{x_1,\ldots, x_n\}$. So $U^{\complement}=\{x_1,\ldots, x_n\}$.